# How to pass all items of Listbox to Textbox which is in another page? ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, listbox

I have an asp.net project with two web forms. I would like to pass all items of listbox3(which is home page) to textbox that is in statistics page.I try following code but didnt work.

Home page:

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Statistics.aspx?ListBox3");
        }
```

Statistics Page

```
   public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox3.Text = ListBox3.Items;

        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you're looking to enumerate the items, something like `foreach(var item in ListBox3.Items) TextBox3.Text = TextBox3 == "" ? TextBox3.Text + item.ToString() : TextBox3.Text + ", " + item.ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer any controls which are not in the current page with its ID. 
So it may required to keep the items from `ListBox`in Session or pass it through `QueryString`

Home Page

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string Items = string.Empty;
   foreach(var item in ListBox3.Items) 
   {
      Items += item + ",";
   }
   //Session["ListBox3"] = Items;
   Response.Redirect("Statistics.aspx?ListBox3=" + Items);
}
```

Statistics Page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox3.Text = Request.QueryString["ListBox3"].ToString();
   //TextBox3.Text = Session["ListBox3"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I got this error "Redirect URI cannot contain newline characters." for this line " Response.Redirect("Statistics.aspx?ListBox3=" + Items);"

Comment: I dont know actually what all are the content of your list box items

Comment: Better you go with `Session` as it is not good practice to pass long text in `QueryString` and there is a limit for `QueryString` content

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string allItems;
    for(int i = 0; i < ListBox3.Items.Count; i++)
        allItems += ListBox3.Items[i].ToString() + "--";
    Response.Redirect("Statistics.aspx?ListBox3=" + allItems.SubString(0, allItems.Length - 2));
}
```

Access it using

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox3.Text = Request.QueryString["ListBox3"];
    }
}
```

Comment: and in Statistics page should I use like this                                   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox3.Text = allItems.Text;

        }

Comment: Didnt work in first then I have changed the line with substring like this  int m = allItems.Length - 2;
       string mmm = allItems.Substring(0, m);
    Response.Redirect("Statistics.aspx?ListBox3=" + mmm);   and it works now how ever I am just getting first element of listbox not all